# How to View Live Stream from ip-camera from a different network

Tags: node.js, rtsp, ip-camera

I am using node.js to live stream from the axis camera and i have a requirement of viewing it from a remote location on a web-browser. Anyone could help provide a solution for this problem?

....i have a requirement of viewing it from a remote location on a web-browser. Anyone could help provide a solution for this problem?